# Physical consequence of non-metricity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Consider a space time that has some non-metricity i.e. $\nabla_{\mu}g_{\alpha\beta} = -Q_{\mu\alpha\beta}\neq 0$. This would imply that if we have an inner product between two vectors and the vectors are parallel transported then
$$\frac{D}{D\lambda}(a^{\mu}b^{\nu}g_{\mu\nu}) = a^{\mu} b^{\nu} Q_{\beta\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\lambda}$$
We see that the inner product changes along the path. How will we see the physical affect of such a space-time? Maybe if we moved a triangular object in such a space-time along some path, will that triangular object suffer some strains because the area of the triangle is proportional to the inner-product of any of its two sides? If so, how can we compute the strain such an object will go through ?

Comment: What sort of "physics" are you doing here, or rather, what do you expect the answer to be based on? Standard general relativity is based on a metric connection. You can't just change that and get general relativity just with a different connection (at least, it is not *obvious* that that would work). For instance, what's the action supposed to be? The Einstein-Hilbert action enforces metricity of the connection.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think OP is asking for a physically feasible experiment that, combined with the use of this equation, could determine if there is any non-metricity present in the connection of the spacetime metric.

Comment: @K.T. My point is that before we can go look for a specific experiment, we first need an actual idea what the theory is whose predictions we're trying to compare to experiment here. Just saying that the connection is now non-metric is underspecified - to compare this to (quantum) field theories, physical theories are not just their field content, you also need to specify the interactions via the action or some other means.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the most obvious example would be the symmetric teleparallel equivalent of general relativity (vanishing torsion and curvature), where the EH action is replaced by the nonmetricity scalar and the derived field equations are just the Einstein field equations. But the gravitational field equations aren't really necessary for OP's question, one can quite generally talk about physical consequences of nonmetricity (e.g. distorted lightcone structure, changing lengths of of parallel transported vectors, etc) and things like the second clock effect in Weyl spacetimes.